# Написал бота, который должен удалять все сообщения начинающиеся с '+' через определенное время,но выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telebot

Ошибка: telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message identifier is not specified
После первого цикла он удаляет все сообщения,не записывает новые и выдает ошибку

```
import datetime
import telebot
import sqlite3
import schedule
import time


token='<TOKEN>'
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token,parse_mode='MARKDOWN')
timeformat="%Y-%m-%d"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now=f'{now:{timeformat}}'
db= sqlite3.connect('server.db',check_same_thread=False)
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
   messageid BIGINT,
   date TEXT,
   message TEXT);
""")
db.commit()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chatting(message):
    a=list(message.text)
    if a[0]=='+':
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users 
VALUES('{message.message_id}','{now}','{message.text}');")
        db.commit()

def job():
    sql.execute("SELECT messageid FROM users")
    b = sql.fetchall()
    for i in range(len(b)):
        bot.delete_message(chat_id='-1001615667874',message_id=b[i])
        sql.execute("UPDATE users SET messageid = NULL")
        db.commit()


schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

bot.polling()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Оффтоп. `a=list(message.text)` и `if a[0]=='+':` - тут список не нужен, доступ по индексам доступен у строк `if message.text[0] == '+':` - это будет работать. Но для строк лучше использовать метод startswith (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: Оффтоп, вот так значения лучше не передавать `sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES('{message.message_id}','{now}','{message.text}');")`, используйте биндинги - это удобнее и от sql-инъекций защитит, пример: `sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?);", (message.message_id, now, message.text))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `fetchall` возвращает список из кортежей. Каждый кортеж хранит запрашиваемые из `SELECT` значения

Если у вас в `users` в `messageid` будут 4 строки с значениями 1, 2, 3, 4, то `fetchall` вернет `[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]`

При получении значений из `fetchall` по индексам `b[i]` вы получите кортежи т.е. `(1,)` и т.п.

Правильно будет доставать значения из кортежей. Кроме того, тут цикл использует индексы, а вы можете напрямую доставать элементы

Пример:

```
    sql.execute("SELECT messageid FROM users")
    for row in sql.fetchall():
        bot.delete_message(chat_id='-1001615667874', message_id=row[0])
```

Можно сразу в цикле сделать распаковку в переменные:

```
    for message_id, in sql.fetchall():
        bot.delete_message(chat_id='-1001615667874', message_id=message_id)
```

Поместите запуск задачи в отдельный поток и до `bot.polling()`:

```
from threading import Thread
...


def do_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

Thread(target=do_schedule).start()

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Попробовал так сделать теперь оно не выдает ошибку, но и сообщения не удаляет, вставил второй цикл в функцию job, если правильно понял

Comment: @Sub_0, второй? Там одного цикла хватит

Comment: А какой еще нужен, если я правильно понял, то вы написали сверху 2 цикла которые делают одно и то же, если я один из них вставляю в функцию job то после одного прогона выдает ошибку Bad Request: message to delete not found, какой еще тогда цикл надо написать?

Comment: Любой из них может заменить ваш цикл. Вы случаем, не оставили в коде `b = sql.fetchall()`?

Comment: нет, сейчас функция job выглядит так:def job():
    sql.execute("SELECT messageid FROM users")
    for row in sql.fetchall():
        bot.delete_message(chat_id='-1001615667874', message_id=row[0])

Comment: @Sub_0, выглядит правильно. Вы проверяли, что возвращается в `row` из базы? Кст, выглядит подозрительно что id чата - это строка. Посмотрел описание API https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage и это разрешено, но такое ощущение, что если вы передаете туда строку, то он будет искать по названию чата (`username of the target channel`), а не по id

Comment: row возвращает messageid, ошибку, которую выдавало я убрал путем удаление messageid из бд по выполнению цикла, но как только запускается функция job сообщения перестают записываться в бд и соответственно обрабатываться

Comment: @Sub_0, думаю, у вас код после `bot.polling()` выполняется? То, что у вас запущен перед этим бот не помешает? Я цикл с `.run_pending()` в отдельном потоке держал типа https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/7d0b4264956e1fc7fa360a14344b0ba43a9ab76f/bot/db_utils.py#L182 и https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/40914d79c7a735aa6f2bc078028f7ef1015d877c/main.py#L55

Comment: @Sub_0, а что насчет `chat_id='-1001615667874'`, о котором выше писал? Ид как строка нормально обрабатывается? Сообщения удалялись?

Comment: сообщения удалялись, вроде все нормально

Comment: после bot.polling() не выполняется...

Comment: @Sub_0, добавил пример запуска в отдельном потоке в ответ. Сколько геморроя с вашим ботом :D

Comment: @Sub_0, [проголосуйте за мой ответ, если он помог и примите его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, проголосовал.